# Get the change in Percentage between two numbers at two different dates

Tags: sql-server

I have the data in the following format :

```
run_date    test_alias  test_value
12/23/2014    1           12
11/22/2014    1           5
1/20/2015     1           7
2/20/2015     1           9

12/19/2014    2           12.1
2/19/2015     2           12.2
1/18/2015     2           12.3
11/17/2014    2           12.4

2/13/2015     3           4
1/13/2015     3           5
12/13/2014    3           7
11/13/2014    3           8
```

How can i get the id for records where in the % of deviation is between 50% and 80% for the last 3 months from today's date .In this case id 3 and 1 should be picked up since For id 3 the last 3 month value is 4 ,5 and 7 .So % of deviaton in this case is 7-4 =3/4 (75%) which is between 50% and 80%

Any help would be really great

Comment: 4,5 and 7 since i need to filter the based on the last three months

Comment: Can there be more then 1 record per month?

Comment: no just one record per month

Comment: if there are only 2 or 1 record per ID then, what happens?

Comment: Also why 7-4 and not 4-7. When you devide by 4 what is 4? Is it count of records per ID?

Comment: 7 is the value which is the latest and 4 is the one which  is like the value at 3rd month ,so i need to capture the increase in % of vlaues

Comment: there will be one record in every month for a id ,no 2 records in the same for a given id

Comment: `7 is the value which is the latest `, did you mean oldest? because latest will be `2/13/2015`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution. If you have any question please ask:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( ID INT, D DATE, V MONEY )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 1, '20141223', 12 ),
        ( 1, '20141122', 5 ),
        ( 1, '20150120', 7 ),
        ( 1, '20150220', 9 ),
        ( 2, '20141219', 12.1 ),
        ( 2, '20150219', 12.2 ),
        ( 2, '20150118', 12.3 ),
        ( 2, '20141117', 12.4 ),
        ( 3, '20150213', 4 ),
        ( 3, '20150113', 5 ),
        ( 3, '20141213', 7 ),
        ( 3, '20141113', 8 );
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   ID ,
                        D ,
                        V ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY D DESC ) AS RN
               FROM     @t
             )
    SELECT  c1.ID ,
            ( c1.V - c2.V ) / c2.V AS V
    FROM    cte c1
            JOIN cte c2 ON c2.ID = c1.ID
                           AND c2.RN = 1
    WHERE   c1.RN = 3
            AND ( c1.V - c2.V ) / c2.V BETWEEN 0.5 AND 0.8
```

Output:

```
ID  V
3   0.75
```